# Add meta data to Drupal 7-uploaded files

Tags: drupal-7, metadata

Is there a way to add meta data to the files I upload in my Drupal 7 website? I found several modules to add meta data to nodes, pages, or content types. (like NodeWords, Meta tags Node Type, ...)
But I want to create meta data for the files I upload. Is this possible and if it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out http://drupal.org/project/file_entity
It allows you to add fields to files, they're trying to get it into core for D8.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module, it lets you customize all of the different tags used in the page header (meta tags) for search engine indexing.